# quicksect/quicksect.pyx missing from newer quicksect files

Tags: python, pip, cython, spacy

I am trying to install quicksectx for some spaCy work and cannot get it to install properly on a macOS as I get the error

> ValueError: 'quicksect/quicksect.pyx' doesn't match any files

I downloaded the tar file and it is actually missing the file: `quicksect/quicksect.pyx`.
`quicksect/quicksect.cpp` does exist. Does anyone know how to generate a pyx file from a cpp file? Or is there some other way around this?  quicksectx does not seem to be in active development at this time.

Comment: You can't generate the pyx file from the cpp file. But you might be able to use the cpp file directly. You probably just need to change the .pyx filename in `sources` in setup.py to be .cpp.

Comment: Alternatively, is [this](https://github.com/jianlins/quicksectx/tree/master/quicksect) what you're after?

Comment: Based on the last updates to quicksectx being in 2020, it may require spaCy v2, while v3 has been out since early 2021. But quicksectx seems to be abandoned and the requirements aren't clearly documented. You're probably better off finding an alternative. https://github.com/jianlins/quicksectx